# Grid connectivity queries

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given a rectangular grid of size N × M, namely, there are cells (x, y) for 1 ≤ x ≤ N, 1 ≤ y ≤ M.

Two cells are adjacent if they share a side. More formally, two cells (x1, y1), (x2, y2) are adjacent if |x1 − x2| + |y1 − y2| = 1. Between two adjacent cells there can be a wall. Two cells a and b are connected if there is a way between them (in other words there is a sequence of cells c[1], c[2], ..., c[k] such that c[1] = a, c[k] = b, and for each 1 ≤ i < k, c[i] and c[i+1] are adjacent cells without wall between them).

Now we are given Q queries, each of them is of following four types.

1. **1 x y** - Build the wall between cells (x, y) and (x, y+1). If there is already exist a wall between them, this query is ignored.
2. **2 x y** - Build the wall between cells (x, y) and (x+1, y). If there is already exist a wall between them, this query is ignored.
3. **3 x1 y1 x2 y2** - Check if cells (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) are connected. Answer to this query is a YES or NO
4. **4** - We need to tell the size of the largest connected component. A connected component is a set of sells wherein each two cells are connected. The size of a connected component is a number of the cells in it.

**Note :  We can assume that there are no walls on the grid before the queries.**

Now given N , M and Q queries we need to tell answer for query of type 3 and 4.

My Approach : I am currently thinking to do it by making a graph and then doing dfs sort of thing for each query. Can this approach be made efficient or is there some other better approach to solve this problem ?

The size of grid is 1000 X 1000 at max. And queries can be up to 10^6

**Example** : Let N=3 and M=4 and at start we are asked query of type 3 that is (1,1) connected to (3,4) then answer is YES as earlier grid is like this :

http://postimg.org/image/5qoug2dov/

Now suppose we have queries of type 1 and 2 and grid become something like this :

http://postimg.org/image/tm14jtg9h/

Now the answer for same query 3 is NO

Comment: [As seen on CodeChef](http://www.codechef.com/MARCH15/problems/MTRWY), part of their March 2015 Long Challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can answer queries offline, then working on them in reverse order turns this into an incremental connectivity problem that is perfect for a disjoint-set data structure whose root nodes are augmented with the total number of nodes in the set.

Comment: Please explain this : "root nodes are augmented with the total number of nodes in the set."